# How can I make a button appear once my timer hits 0?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a timer counting down from 15, it works fine. Is there a way that when it hits 0, a button will appear that wasn't previously on the ViewController?

Comment: try this..if(Timer == 0){[yourButtonName setHidden:FALSE];} now when timer reaches 0.it will show your button and put [yourButtonName setHidden:TRUE]; in viewdidload..so,it never shows at the beginning as your question demands.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSTimer *yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0f target:self selector:@selector(showButton:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

- (void)changePage:(id)iSender {
    [yourButton setHidden:FALSE];
}
```

**Hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Just you need is to have a look on hidden property and set when timer is 0.

```
[yourbutton setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide it by default with

```
[yourButton setHidden:YES];
```

and when the timer reaches 0, set hidden property to NO.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourButton setHidden:YES];
if(timer==0)
{

[yourButton setHidden:NO];

}
```

try this way.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways you can do this:

1. Hide your button using the UIView's hidden property. Once your timer fires and your code is running, you can change the hidden value to show the button
2. If the fire is only fired once, you can add the button as a subview once the selector is fired. If the selector/timer is only fired once, you might want to use GCD dispatch_after function
3. You can use the alpha/enable property

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonToShow;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.buttonToShow.hidden = YES;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15.0 target:self selector:@selector(showButton) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];   
}

- (void)showButton
{
    self.buttonToShow.hidden = NO;
}
```